# I have been blocked for nearly a year from asking questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, post-ban

When I first joined Stack Overflow, I wasn't really that good at coding or at asking questions. As a result, I had a block (question ban) put on my account.

Now (two years later), I have become proficient in coding and have boosted my reputation points from 15 to 606 after answering questions and editing questions/answers! I know that the blocks can last a long time, but I didn't think that the one I have would last for years! Does anyone have any suggestions on how I an get it lifted?

I have read the Help Center several times. I have fixed my 'old' posts as best I could. Now it seems that even those have been deleted.

Comment: The question ban is not about how good of a programmer you are, but about the quality of your questions.  Very inexperienced programmers can ask good questions, experienced programmers can ask bad questions.

Comment: Posting blocks have no time limits; they are based solely on the quality of your posts.

Comment: my older questions seem to have been deleted. It's very strange.

Comment: even then, I remember going back after reading the help center and fixing the questions as best I could.

Comment: Some might say that you have boosted your rep from 15 to 606 BECAUSE you have been question-banned.  I couldn't possibly comment:)

Comment: @www139 Very low quality content is deleted, both manually and automatically, if it cannot be or simply isn't improved to be of value to the community.

Comment: You have a series of older heavily downvoted deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454041/there-are-some-random-characters-in-my-code-how-do-i-fix-it , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325564/is-there-a-software-programming-language-that-has-object-oriented-as-optional-in , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863823/how-validate-a-form-with-javascript-then-send-it-with-php . These were removed automatically by the system after being closed. I'm not sure if these could be improved, so as a worst case you could write SE and request they be dissociated from your account.

Comment: what do you think I should do about those 'bad' questions?

Comment: You seem to be actually putting effort into getting your account unbanned; it seems unfair to keep you from reaching that goal forever. However, since it's an automatic ban, there is nothing we can do for you. Try writing to team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: A moderator can fix it. Manually undelete the auto-deleted questions one by one, then set them to community wiki, and re-delete them.