# How do we get out of question ban?

Tags: support, downvotes, post-ban

I got a question ban on SO because of some unknown reason: my questions were downvoted even if they were well-formatted and well-organized. Lately, I've been answering lots of questions contributing to the site and helping people. I've edited my questions but no one pays attention to them as they have accepted answers.

[In the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/4354477) it's said

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.
>
> The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out".

And

> Before you do *anything else*, fix your existing posts!

What does *anything else* mean?
How do we *contribute to the site*?
What can we do to get out of question ban?

([Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286795/4354477) is practically the same question posted some seconds before I posted mine, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286797/4354477) is another similar question)

**Edit:** none of my questions were marked as duplicates.

Comment: One thing you could do is to check for duplicates before posting.

Comment: Yeah, @www139 didn't check for dups either.

Comment: @Louis, I've linked this question as I didn't quite get the idea of its answers.

Comment: The point (granted, it was a bit subtle) being that if you're trying to prove you're now ready to ask quality questions, the fact that you haven't even searched for duplicates of the single most frequently asked meta question (by a wide margin) doesn't bode well for you.  Posting a low quality question to say that you should be able to keep asking questions...

Comment: @Servy, see the linked questions and link to Help Center. I've searched a lot but didn't find any advices except 'edit your previous posts'. About low quality - I've never thought SO has _so high_ quality levels. OK, I'm gonna start taking some lessons about asking questions...

Comment: So you searched for duplicates *after posting a duplicate question*?  And you think that that makes your question well researched?  That's not how that works.  You should be searching for duplicates *before* you ask your question, so that you don't need to ask it in the first place.

Comment: @Servy, first I read everything I could find on this topic and then posted this question. You can see, the first revision already contains the links.

Comment: No, actually it doesn't.  And if you read everything on the topic, then you wouldn't have just asked a bunch of questions that had already been answered thousands of times.

Comment: @Servy, by the way, is _contributing to site_ count in reputation points? Can I get out of ban by overweighting the lost reputation? Or by getting more upvotes than downvotes?

Comment: @ForceBru There are many factors taken into consideration by the post ban.  Votes are one of the factors, but not the only factor.

Comment: @Servy, which are these factors? Or is it secret information?

Comment: I'm done repeating information already readily accept from the many hundreds of duplicate questions.  If you want to learn more, do your research, all of this has been discussed to death.

Answer (score 3):

> How do we *contribute to the site*?

You answered this yourself in the first paragraph:

> Lately, I've been answering lots of questions contributing to the site and helping people.

---

> What can we do to get out of question ban?

Read the part after the "anything else". Then, anything that isn't that, is "anything else".

Note that while it says contributing to the site in other ways can help, it's not *nearly* as effective as that other thing it tells you to do, which is why it says to do that *before* you try anything else.

Comment: Well, 'I've been answering questions, etc', but I'm still banned

Comment: @ForceBru Then apparently the positive contributions you've made are not enough to offset the negative contributions you've made.

Comment: @Servy, wow, then I'm sort of mighty dragon destroying the world and making negative contributions :p

Comment: @ForceBru That, or the answers you've been providing simply aren't that valuable.  Given that most are zero scored and I'm seeing about as many answers with a negative score as a positive score, and almost none of the positive scored answers have more than a score of 2, I'd go with the latter.

Comment: I also have been banned from asking questions, and I would improve my existing questions, but they have been automatically deleted by a bot. Will improving them even matter any more?

Comment: @Mike Payne: I don't moderate or actively use the site anymore, and I'm gonna go out on a limb and say no, it probably doesn't matter anymore. The algorithm is not perfect, kinda weaksauce actually, and I don't know how much better the community treats questions wrt voting these days.

Comment: I am really disappointed in the ban and that StackOverflow is unfriendly enough to ban members in the first place. I try to provide answers where I can, though I find that the site has plenty of users more knowledgeable than me, and I come here for help only to get banned for asking questions that don't confirm to a set of rules? It honestly makes Stack Overflow seem a lot less friendly to newcomers and more like a club of elitists.

Comment: @MikePayne Stackoverflow isn't a exactly a help desk. It may look like one, but the goal is more... grand than simply helping each and every person who has a question to ask. Rather, the goal here is for people to not *need* to ask because it's already been asked and answered. Questions that are unclear, or too subjective, too broad, etc don't further that goal.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything related to my question when I searched. I would have much rather been able to read an already documented solution!

Comment: @Mike Payne: That's a common complaint and it is disappointing that the state of affairs hasn't improved after so many years. It doesn't help that duplicates aren't easy to find when you're a newcomer in the first place.

Comment: So since I'm supposed to edit my original questions to improve the, but I have already edited them to provide the missing data and they have been deleted by a bot, what am I to do now? Am I just screwed?

Comment: Can anyone provide some clarification on this?

Comment: Can anyone please help? It seems as there is no other resource as good as this one for getting help. Except regarding my ban, that is. :(

Comment: @MikePayne Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th The post is rather exhaustive on what to do/how to proceed when you are question banned, but you really _do_ have to read it _all_. Also, please don't repeatedly spam comments under an unrelated answer. Ask a full-fledged question if you want some help...  don't continue bothering Boltclock.